# How do I create a service account Jenkins

Tags: installation, user-accounts, jenkins

When installing Jenkins - Windows10 not domain joined - I get to a service configuration step, where in the past I would have either used my own interactive logon account to run the service under, or woudl crreate a new user account.
I'm unsure how to even do the latter on Windows10 Pro. I'm clearly wanting to create a "virtual account", but not finding a simple explanation of all the implications. Where am I going wrong?

I found this confusing solution but got stuck https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e06a5a26-7b25-467f-acc6-09c215f8071f/windows-10-how-to-create-local-service-accounts-for-iis-sql-btsync-and-other-services?forum=win10itprosecurity

I thought this answer would help me, but it's aimed at the same problem or no? [How to Create Local Windows Desktop Service Accounts?](https://superuser.com/questions/1035324/how-to-create-local-windows-desktop-service-accounts)

Comment: How does the answer to that question, not answer your question, seems applicable to your situation.

Comment: The answer covered steps which are either incomplete, require additional knowledge, or were merely disabled on my system for some reason since it was perhaps assuming a domain joined host or other pre-condition which I was unaware of? User can create accounts with a PIN, passwords are not settable.